# Do multi-target moves get stronger against a single target?

Tags: pokemon-series

I know that in double battles, Surf, Rock Slide and generally any move that hits more than one target has its power nerfed (I think it's a 1/3 drop?)

My question is, does it get full power if there is only one target to be hit (such as when the opponent is on their last Pokémon, or if their other Pokémon already fainted?)

Similarly, if it misses all other targets, does it get its normal power against the one it hits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Bulbapeida:

"Some (moves), such as Surf, can have noticeably different effects. Moves that hit multiple Pokémon have their damage reduced by 25%, unless all other Pokémon have fainted at that point."

So surf will deal full damage if the opposing team has only a single pokemon, but have its damage reduced if it just misses one of the targets.

http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Double_battle#Effects_on_moves